# Firebase image URL not working Angular NgStyle

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a challenge rendering an image via the firebase resource image URL.

The template code is as follows:

```
                <div [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/app.appspot.com/o/images%2Fdownload%20(1)-1573413772018?alt=media&token=6dacb361-c996-4cbf-a672-73ab449e149f
            dgg)', 'background-position': 'center',
            'background-repeat': 'no-repeat',
            'background-size': 'cover'}" class="img-wrapper"></div>
```

When I inspect the element in dev tools the `background-image` prop is not being applied

What am I missing here?

**UPDATE**

I have tried sanitizing the url and used the code below

```
                <div [style.background-image]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(article.articleImgUrl)" [ngStyle]="{'background-position': 'center',
            'background-repeat': 'no-repeat',
            'background-size': 'cover'}" class="img-wrapper"></div>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
```

Comment: Are you getting any console errors? This might be angular's sanitization causing an issue

Comment: @MathieudeLorimier no, no errors, check the question update

Comment: Shouldn't you use `bypassSecurityTrustUrl`

Comment: No, remember it has to be background-image: url(...)

Comment: I've updated the code to be [style.background-image]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle('url'+ article.articleImgUrl + ')')" but still

Comment: I understand but the value you are concatenating is an url (either base64 or not). So you should give it a try.

Comment: Ohh yeah I get you now, I will give it a try, I am AFK at the moment, I will update the thread when I get it working,  thanks

Comment: @MathieudeLorimier check the answer I have posted, thanks for assisting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by having a function call in the template:

```
[style.background-image]="article.getImageUrl()";
```

In the class file I have an implementation of the function:

```
const getImageUrl = () => this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(`url(${articleData.articleImgUrl})`);
```

Comment: Though it would be nice to understand why the above solution works, that is, why does returning the URL from a functions solves the issue?